# Как добавить номер телефона на сайт

Tags: php

Как добавить номер телефона на сайт, платформа OpenCart

Answer (score 5):

1.Редактируем контроллер: \catalog\controller\common\header.php
Добавляем там:

```
$this->data['telephone'] = $this->config->get('config_telephone');
```

2.Редактируем шаблон: \catalog\view\theme[ваш_шаблон]\template\common\header.tpl

В нужном вам месте выводим номер, вставив код:

```
<?php echo $telephone; ?>
```